# Change language in community (custom component)

Tags: lightning, lightning-community

I need to change the language of my Salesforce Community. We can add a standard component (Language Selector --> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_language_picker.htm&type=5), but it not is pretty ;)

I have tried to change the LanguageLocaleKey of user (the component (buttons) change the language of the user), but the community not change the language (even with F5 it does not change the language). Is it possible to change the language in a custom component?

Thanks

This is a easy example:

**component**

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid_vertical-align-center">
    <lightning:button label="German" title="German" onclick="{!c.changeLanguageGer}" class="borderPhoto" />
    <lightning:button label="English" title="English" onclick="{!c.changeLanguageEng}" class="borderPhoto" />
</div>
```

**js**

```
changeLanguageGer : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.changeLang");
    action.setParams({
        lang: "de"
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a){
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

changeLanguageEng : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.changeLang");
    action.setParams({
        lang: "en_US"
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a){
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

**apex**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string changeLang(String lang) {
    String currentuserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    User currentUserInfo = [select LanguageLocaleKey from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    currentUserInfo.LanguageLocaleKey = lang;
    update currentUserInfo;
    return 'OK';
}
```

*Edited:*
I check with event: $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
But the page of community not refresh.

```
changeLanguageEng : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.changeLang");
    action.setParams({
        lang: "en_US"
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a){
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: So looks like you already have the custom component created. What is the behavior? You should be able to determine if this works or not. Are you encountering any issue? If yes, then you may like to [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/250823/edit) to provide that specific issue for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: The component changes the language of user (field "LanguageLocaleKey"), but the comunity not change the language. Ok I edit the question with more details. Thanks

Comment: @Jayant Das or anyone can help me?? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();`? Can you try once using it in the success of the callback functions you have in JS to see if it refreshes the view or not.

Comment: Yes, I used this event, but it not work (I think that this event not work in community page)

Comment: This event works in any experience. I couldn't see a reason why after refreshing the language doesn't work.

Comment: I can not format the code in this comment, I edit the post with it. I will try redirect to the same page...

Comment: @Jayant Das, do you know what field changes the standard component "Language selector" ? I change the language in this component and LanguageLocaleKey field of User object not is modified

Comment: It's the correct field. So it seems the field itself is not getting updated in the backend. Your issue is not on the component then, but in Apex. You should verify it from that front.

Comment: My custom component changes the language field and not the language of community; and the standard component not change the language field but if the language of community changes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the exact same method to change my community languages

What I do for refreshing is - after server side has finished, I am refreshing the whole page with `location.reload();`, I have added my solution to your method:

```
changeLanguageEng: function(component, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.changeLang");
    action.setParams({
        lang: "en_US"
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            var changedOK = response.getReturnValue();
            if (changedOK == 'OK')
                location.reload();
            else {
                alert('error, changed not OK: ' + changedOK);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('error in state: ' + state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: ouuu yeahh. location.reload() works correctly
Thanks